# Test to determine whether a huge series of integers is random or there is a pattern?

Tags: probability, random, hypothesis-testing

I have a series of integers in which some integers occur more than others.  I want to know if there is a test to determine whether these integers are randomly distributed or some integers occur more than others due to some inherent property of the data being collected? The integers are in the range of 0-9 only

I want a test which can say that there is a statistically significant difference between the frequency of the integers. 
For example:

1,9,8,5,0,3....5000 such numbers

0-9%

1-11%

.

.

.

Is there a significant difference between the occurrence of the integers or it is just random.

Edit: 
The data series has more than 5000 observations. 
I am only concerned about the frequency.

Comment: Is the frequency of the integers the only aspect you are looking at, or is there anything else?

Comment: What do you mean by a huge series? Thousands, billions, dozens?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test

Comment: @almagest I have added the information required

Comment: It is easy to do a calculation which determines if, for example, counts of 40,36,55,19,50,46,52,39,43,75 for the digits 0,...,9 is a plausible outcome. But you might also want to look at pairs. You just about have enough data to make that worthwhile. Certainly, for example, 15 occurrences of 3,4 would raise suspicions that the sequence was not random, even if the digit counts looked ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned about the frequency, then a simple computer program which goes through all the integers and counts the frequency of each will suffice. Once you have the frequency table, you can do further analysis if required.

(From a frequency table, you can calculate the mean, median, standard deviation, and mode of the data, and see whether it looks like a normal distribution, etc.)

Comment: I have done that tabulation.  My question is that even though some integers appear more than others (like 11% vs 9%), is there a way to determine that this is not due to randomness and there is actually a statistically significant variation in frequency?

Comment: @Asox That kind of variation does not look unusual for randomly generated digits. Why not add that data to your question?

Comment: @Asox 'Statistically significant' is not an absolute term. What do you define to be 'statistically significant'? If a difference of 2 percentage points is significant for your application, then the numbers are not random.

Comment: I have added that data.

Comment: Could you add the % for the rest of the digits (2,3 etc) then we could give you a more useful answer.